# Class constructor: How can I set a default class in a List

Tags: dart, flutter

```
class Column {
  final String columnName;
  final String dataType;

  Column({
    this.columnName,
    this.dataType
  });
}

class Table {
  final List<Column> children;
  Table({
    this.children = const <Column>[]
  });
}

main(){
  Table(
    children: 
  );
}
```

My question is I want to show the `<Column>[ ]` in the "children:" the same approach with `Row(children: <Widget>[ ])`

Comment: and your question is ...? `"How can I set a default class in a List"` does not say much

Comment: What is "default class". What is the problem you actually try to solve?

Comment: Just like the Row widget it has a named constructor children and it gives you the default value "<Widget>[]" by typing the children and then you put the widgets available on it. In my case, I want to show "<Column>[]" as default when I type the named constructor children of Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got what you want to achieve, your implementation is fine. The thing is, when you type the `Row` constructor and `children: <Widget>[]` appears, that is something your code editor does. It does not depend on the default value you gave to that constructor parameter.
So if you try to instantiate your `Table` class, even without the default param value, for example in VSCode (with the Dart plugin installed), the editor will suggest you to pass the `children` parameter, and if you press Enter to accept the suggestion, it will type for you the empty list.